# Cached results in Linq Query

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

> **Edit:** At first I thought this was related to component views, but I've managed to isolate the issue a bit.

I have the following class:

```
public class TmpContext
{
    public NYPContext db { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetUserListFromSelection(int[] selection)
    {
        var userList = from u in db.UsuariosIntranet
                       join su in selection on u.Id equals su
                       select new SelectListItem()
                       {
                           Text = string.Format("{0}, {1}", u.ApellidoPaterno, u.Nombres),
                           Value = u.Id.ToString(),
                       };
        return userList;
    }
}
```

I have a view that receives the class above as model, and have the following code in it:

```
@{
    // First list
    var list1 = new int[] { 4947850 };
    var a = Model.GetUserListFromSelection(list1);
    foreach (var user in a)
    {
        <p class="tag">@user.Text</p>
    }

    // Second list, note the different ids
    var list2 = new int[] { 2, 3 };
    var b = Model.GetUserListFromSelection(list2);

    foreach (var user in b)
    {
        <p class="tag">@user.Text</p>

    }

    // Third list
    var o = list1.ToList();
    // add a new id
    o.Add(5185969);
    // int[] otra = ;
    var c = Model.GetUserListFromSelection(o.ToArray());
    foreach (var user in c)
    {
        <p class="tag">@user.Text</p>
    }
}
```

The expected results are three different lists, but somehow I get the first items repeated three times.

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: This should work. Is Model of type TmpContext? I did not know that EF can translate a join to a local collection... Is db.UsuariosIntranet of type IQueryable?

Comment: Yes, Model is a `TmpContext` object, I just wrote it for the purposes of this question. `db.UsuariosIntranet` is declared as `public DbSet<UsuarioIntranet> UsuariosIntranet { get; set; }`

Comment: So far I have no idea what the problem might be. Let's investigate. Start SQL Profiler and see what queries there are. Are there 1 or 3? Do the parameter values look alright? Also, place a breakpoint in GetUserListFromSelection. Is it being called 3 times with the parameters you expect?

Comment: When debugging GetUserListFromSelection, I see that the received parameter is correct, but the IQueryable is always the same. It doesn't matter if I change the view afterwards, and what parameters I use; once it got results the first time, it always returns the same values, hence my suspicions about this being cache related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a bug, and it is already fixed. Talk about fast turnaround!

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2826